# How to get correct SVG dimensioning / aspect ratio?

Tags: svg

I'm making some pointers by hand coding svgs. I have defined a polygon using points in a 100x100 square and gotten the aspect ratio that I want by setting the width and height attributes of the outer SVG element. Here is a jsfiddle of the graphic: http://jsfiddle.net/62WpR/.

Unfortunately, the text is being compressed by the width and height attributes. Is there any way to use these without compressing text, or doing something silly like applying a transform to it?

If this is not possible, I guess I will have to define paths in a coordinate space with the final aspect ratio that I want. Disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it kind of.

By setting the viewbox to a 1:2 ratio and using transforms on both of the polygons in the svg, I was able to get the dimensions I wanted. As long as the dimensions in the CSS are set to a 2:1 ratio, the graphic will display right.

I have also made judicious use of the preserveAspectRatio property to keep the image at the same aspect ratio. I'm only setting the width in the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/62WpR/3/

```
<svg baseProfile="full" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" id="svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 100 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="scale(1 .5)" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke="black">
       <polygon vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fill="#666" id="tab" points="20.0,95.0 5.0,50.0 20.0,5.0 90.0,5.0 95.0,15.0 95.0,85.0 90.0,95.0"></polygon>
       <polygon vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fill="#FFEA00" id="insert" points="25.0,95.0 10.0,50.0 25.0,5.0" visibility="visible"></polygon>
  </g>                                    
  <text fill="white" font-size="30" text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="36">999</text>
</svg>​
```